# GCP Load Balancer redirect while keeping query parameters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

In my GCP project am a doing a Host and path rules redirect on one of my load balancers. I am trying to get the redirect to pass the query parameters, but it is not.

Essentially trying to do:

subdomain.domain.com?foo=bar -> [www.domain.com/path?foo=bar](http://www.domain.com/path?foo=bar).

The redirect works to the path, but it does not keep the query params. From what I can see here, it should work.

https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/traffic-management#redirects

Redirect to a different URL formed by modifying the host, path, or both the host and path portion of the URL, and either stripping out **or retaining any query parameters**.

Comment: People will need to see what's the current configurations to be able to determine what's wrong. Edit your question and add more details how do you configure the re-direction and also also show current and expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

### In Google Cloud, the **stripQuery** field can also be used with a Load Balancer, specifically the GCP HTTP(S) Load Balancer. This feature allows you to **configure whether the query string present in the incoming request's URL will be included or removed when the request is forwarded** to a backend service.

> When stripQuery is set to false, the query string will be included in
> the path when forwarding traffic to the backend service.

**i.e:** if a request is made to "example.com/path?key=value", and stripQuery is set to false, the request will be forwarded to the backend service as if it were made to "example.com/path?key=value".

---

By disabling the *stripQuery* feature in Google Cloud Load balancer we can forward the query params to the new host we have redirected to.

---

Here is a configuration YAML we can use to redirect the site to another site preserving the query parameters.

```
defaultService: projects/example/global/backendServices/example-test
name: example-matcher1
routeRules:
- urlRedirect:
    stripQuery: false
    hostRedirect: ie.example.com
    redirectResponseCode: MOVED_PERMANENTLY_DEFAULT
```

If you are using DefaultRedirect in Advanced host and path rule:
You should uncheck the ***Strip query*** in Google Cloud Load Balancer Edit Page for *Advanced Route Rules*  Routing Rules .
Reference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSUKC.png)